# How do I remove checkbox border?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Is it possible to remove the borders around a checkbox so that it appears invisible?  I have it placed in a DIV with a color background.

Comment: for all other elements I would say `border-width: 0`, but i tried this in Firefox, and it always displays the border in `width: 1.6` even when I try to change it in firefox developer console.

Comment: For anyone struggling with designing checkboxes, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58792508/9158986

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, its not possible to remove borders on browser native checkboxes (it will not work in all browsers), You will have to write your own checkbox-like state widget to implement this. Check out [Nice forms](http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/) if you want to style your regular form controls with custom styling

Answer (score 15):

As this is the first result for me when searching for "remove checkbox border" in Google, let me mention that checkbox default styling could be removed in all browsers except IE with the [`appearance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance) property:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

Comment: since this thread comes first on google search, someone should make your answer the correct one!

Comment: When I add this then I cannot click the checkbox anymore

Answer (score 8):

For FireFox: try border:none.
For IE try: style="background:transparent;border:0"

The other solution is to create your own images for checked and unchecked displaying the appropriate onclick of the image.

Comment: Works for removing border in IE8: `style="background:transparent;border:0"`

Comment: Works not in current firefox version. Even if I set border or border-width to 0, firefox changes this to 1.6 (even when I directly edit the border with in firefox debug console).

Adding `appearance: none;` like said in other answers, saved my day

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a late answer, but a CSS expert I work with gave me this way to get rid of the border around a checkbox (and probably radio button) in IE10:

- Set the border color to the same color as the page's background.
- Apply a box-shadow of "none" to it.

That's it. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: gray;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    left: -5px;
    top: -5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS this is possible by setting the web kit appearance to none. Something like this

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

### I just try something relevent, hope it'll solve your problem!

Actually you can't remove only border but you can use appearance property to remove whole element body, then you can implement your styling and make the checkbox as you want.. **Here you can see below:-**

```css
input[type='checkbox']{
transform:scale(2);
appearance:none;
border:2px solid black;
height:50px;
width:50px;
margin-left:2em; margin-top:2em; font-size:40px; position:relative; }
input[type='checkbox']:checked:before{
 content:'\2713'; background:blue; width:100%; height:100%; top:0;
left:0;
 display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; color:white; font-weight:bold; }
```

```html
<input type='checkbox'>
```

Answer (score -3):

You would have to use some widget or a custom ui of some sort to remove the borders.

I'm not sure if this works: `<input type="checkbox" style="border: 0;" />`