# How do I format the checkbox using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a datagridview in which I'm showing a checkbox for a boolean value. And it looks like a regular checkbox.

But what we want is to remove the actual box, so that only the check mark shows. Is this possible? And if so does anyone by chance know how?

I'm using C# if that helps, and this is on WindowsForms.

Comment: Could you not just display a tick image?

Comment: Can you not just disable the checkbox?

Comment: if you are willing to migrate to WPF, you can easily do it via DataTemplates :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a post talking about eliminating checkbox borders

[How do I remove checkbox border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544690/how-do-i-remove-checkbox-border)

In short, its not really possible without a big work around. I would chose Ryan Amies solution of using a custom image

Edit: Wrong link.