# Firefox - Remove border from undecorated checkbox

Tags: html, css, firefox, checkbox, border

I have a checkbox the has the `appearance: none;`. This working in chrome, but in Firefox it leaves behind an inset border that I cannot remove. I have tried `border: none` already.

I've a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jcJJ5/

Comment: What is your doctype declaration?

Comment: Wouldn't display none in a checkbox rule take away the entire box?

Comment: @AlexW I still want the checkbox to show my own background image, just not with the border.

Comment: @ZoltanToth Yes, I have that applied. It does remove the checkbox look, but still leaves the border.

Comment: I've added a fiddle to the question.

Comment: @MathWizz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544690/how-do-i-remove-checkbox-border

Comment: @AlexW I saw that, but I assumed the asker was referring to the normal border (`appearance: checkbox`).

Comment: @MathWizz Here's another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460501/how-to-change-checkboxs-border-style-in-css

Comment: @MathWizz I have never tried this but I hope it helps.. <http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/> orignally posted on <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544690/how-do-i-remove-checkbox-border>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that setting any properties on the checkbox will help.

The only simple workaround that I have found is to wrap the checkbox in a `<div>`, and obscure the borders.

See my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcJJ5/14/).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="checkbox-container"><input type="checkbox" /></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    left: -5px;
    top: -5px;
}
.checkbox-container {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

By the way, (in Firefox at least), setting `background` doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

you could try setting a -moz-box-shadow: with the color of the two lines that are lighter to cover the dark inset the firefox creates...

also, i tried playing around in firebug and if u turn of -moz-appearance: none, the checkbox is completely fine and has a normal styling that you shouldn't need to play around with.

Answer (score 0):

**Update from 2021**, it seems that the `appearance` has been working fine in Firefox for some time now. This [issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=605985) covers the process.