# Remove firefox checkbox border

Tags: html, css

The question is:
How to remove that border in FireFox?
[image]

When running at Google Chrome it is OK
[image]

```css
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  box-sizing: borer-box;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  background: url(//i.imgur.com/qBOXbpe.png) left top no-repeat;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  background: url(//i.imgur.com/qBOXbpe.png) -30px top no-repeat
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background: url(//i.imgur.com/qBOXbpe.png) -15px top no-repeat;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked {
  background: url(//i.imgur.com/qBOXbpe.png) -45px top no-repeat;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:focus {
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: FF is quite difficult about checkboxes. Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552228/firefox-remove-border-from-undecorated-checkbox

Comment: [At least four similar questions on Stack.](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=css%20firefox%20checkbox%20border)

Comment: @Michael_B please note that I have different html structure. In my code there is only input witout label.

Comment: @breq If you want to style checkbox, don't use it directly. each browser deal with it differently. here you can see a way for changing checkbox style: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953