# Hide only checkbox box not it's text in Android

Tags: android

How I can hide checkbox box only, but not checkbox text in .
`Checkbox` is created programmatically.

`myCheckBox.setVisibility(View.GONE)` hides the whole checkbox with text also included. I would like to show only text but not box icon.

Looking forward to hear from you soon.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063135/removing-the-box-from-the-checkbox-in-android.

Answer (score 11):

This works for me:

```
Drawable transparentDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
myCheckBox.setButtonDrawable(transparentDrawable);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do like, don't give text value in checkbox element,you use separate textview for text and hide checkbox.
Example

```
         <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hindustan"/>
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:id="@+id/hindustanCB"/>
```