# Remove checkbox outlne

Tags: checkbox, outline

I am trying to remove the outline from a classic checkbox!

html

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="check" />Remember Me</label>
</div>
```

css

```
#check{
  outline: none;
}
```

Link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7cRL3/17/

The answer must be pretty easy but I can't figure out why it is not working!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544690/how-do-i-remove-checkbox-border

Comment: Yeah, it seems the question has already been asked before. Though if anyone has a better solution than creating his own widget it would be great!